# Rails: How do you associate a stylesheet to a layout?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My application has a controller that uses a different layout called "special":

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  layout "special"
  ...
end
```

So I've created a new `layouts/special.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "special" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
 <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I also created a new corresponding `stylesheets/special.css`

The problem is when I try to access the page with the "special" layout I'm getting an exception:

> Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError
>   in Sessions#new

```
special.css isn't precompiled
```

I've already executed `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, but it didn't fix the problem.
What's wrong? How do you associate a stylesheet to a layout in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails only precompiles your `application.css` and `application.js` files (or their `.scss`, `.less` or `.coffee` equivalents).

If you want an additional file to be precompiled, you must add it to the `precompile` array on your `config/environments/production.rb`, like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( special.css )
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification from the accepted answer - the docs suggest adding the precompiled assets in `config/initializers/assets.rb`. This makes sense so that they are available in all environments without having to repeat the config set up for each. So I created that file and added the fully qualified config attribute:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( special.css )
```